# time.sleep does not seem accurate with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, time, automation

so I use time.sleep to let my automation testing have a human like time and behaviour but the time.sleep looks like a bit faster or something (sometimes it does not even look it worked) is it build like this? and should I use the implicict wait ? and what's the diffrence between them?

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score -1):

you can use `webdriver.implicitly_wait("time in s")` instead if you prefer.
The difference is, that implicitly waits only in the browser, while time.sleep waits in the script itself.